# Making <img> responsive and SEO friendly in the same way as using background-img

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, seo, background-image

I want to make img tag responsive  in the same way as in a div using background image with  background-position: center and  background-size: cover
My problem is, that I'll be posting a lot of images(in a **grid layout**) that don't have the same width or height. Soo, if I use img tag with height:auto I get different height everytime.
Current sollutions:

1.
 Using bg-image and 1pixel image for width and height:

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://example.com/img.jpeg);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover; width="30%" ">
<img src="/1pix.png" height="200px" alt="Alt text">
</div>
```

2. Using background image and img inside with visibility:hidden

   ```
   <div style="background-mage:url(http://example.com/img.jpeg);
   style="background-position: center;
   background-size: cover; height="200px" width="30%">
   <img src="/example.jpeg"  style="visibility:hidden" alt="Alt text">
   </div>
   ```

3.Using multiple img sizes (small,large,medium)

Is there a way to make img tag work in a fluid grid,make it look as nice as in bg-image(bg-contain) or to make bg-image SEO friendly with some sort of meta tag that works in a same way than the alt tag.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a polyfill for IE, the `object-fit` CSS property can help you out here. It's basically `background-size` but for HTML tags. You would need to define a height and width for the `<img>` and add `object-fit: cover;`.

Browser coverage for `object-fit` can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) and a polyfill for IE8+ can be found [here](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit).

Comment: It does not work on Edge either, even if they are working on it. I'd stick to background-image positioning until Edge implements it. Explorer is still very popular and using a hack to make it work would defeat the purpose, in my opinion.